# Update the data in spring boot using jpa hibernate

Tags: java

I have two classes Country and State like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "State")
 @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
 public class State {
   @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

 @Column(name = "statename")
 private String stateName;

  @Column(name = "statecode")
  private String stateCode;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
  @JoinColumn(name = "country")
  private Country country;
 }
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Country")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Country implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
@Column(name = "countryName")
private String countryName;

@Column(name = "countrycode")
private String countryCode;
}
```

also their DTO counterparts

```
public class StateDTO { 
    private String stateName; 
    private String stateCode; 
    private CountryDTO country; 
}

public class CountryDTO { 
    private String countryName; 
    private String countryCode; 
}
```

and the repository implementation

```
@Repository 
public interface StateRepository extends JpaRepository<State, Long> { 
}
```

i need to update my state class. i have written in service like

```
public String updateState(StateDTO statedto,Long stateId) {
State state = stateRepository.findById(stateId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("State", "id", stateId));
    state.setStateName(statedto.getStateName());
    state.setStateCode(statedto.getStateCode());
    stateRepository.save(state);}
```

but I am not getting country Name. If I set the country I am getting issue.

Comment: `i am getting issue` what issue are you facing?

Comment: while updating data into State, that country name is inserting into the Country table

Comment: can you please update your code with the contents of `StateDto` and `stateRepository`? Also watch out because all values like `private String stateName;` are camel-case and all `@Column(name = "statename")` are lower-case but `@Column(name = "countryName")`. Is at database level the column called `countryName` and not `countryname`?. This may be causing the issue.

Comment: public class StateDTO {
    private String stateName;
    private String stateCode;
    private CountryDTO country;
}

Comment: public class CountryDTO {
    private String countryName;
    private String countryCode;
}

Comment: @Repository
public interface StateRepository extends JpaRepository<State, Long> {

}

Comment: have you checked the database field `countryName` is really called `countryName` and not `countryname`?  
If this is not the problem, could you please add in your main post as an edit the structure of your database?

Comment: its taking like country_name